downloading chrome older versions in centos7 based linux system
I am looking for older versions of Google Chrome Stable. Now, older versions for Windows are available easily but I need it for Linux, preferably RPMs.
Where can I get Chrome's stable older versions?
I was unable to find the rpm any where, can some one help me out in this, I  am using centos7 based linux system.
